# Defining functions and using map in jq

Tags: jq, filter

Can you explain to me how the following two differ?

```
jq ´def addvalue(f): . + [f]; map(addvalue(.[0]))´

[[1,2],[10,20]]
=> [[1,2,1], [10,20,10]]

jq ´def addvalue(f): f as $x | map(. + $x); addvalue(.[0])´
[[1,2],[10,20]]
=> [[1,2,1,2], [10,20,1,2]]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Summary:  The two functions and the way you call them differ in where the `map()` operation happens and what's used in the addition. This matters as in the first case, the `map()` in the call makes the addition in the function use the first element of *each individual sub-array* of the input array.  In the second case, the `map()` is performed inside the function, and the addition is using *the whole first sub-array* of the input array.

---

In the first function,

```
def addvalue(f): . + [f];
```

you add the array `[f]` to what is assumed to be an array in the input stream. Adding an array to another array has the effect of appending new elements to the array.

You call this `addvalue()` function twice using `map()`; once for each of the arrays `[1,2]` and `[10,20]`.  In the first call, `[f]` will be `[1]`, so you add `1` as a new element in the first array, yielding `[1,2,1]`.  Likewise, you get `[10,20,10]` from the second call when `[f]` is `[10]`.

Adding debugging to the function,

```
def addvalue(f): debug | . + [f]
```

we get the following when calling it as in the question:

```
["DEBUG:",[1,2]]
["DEBUG:",[10,20]]
```

This shows that the function is called twice.  The value `[f]` would be `[1]` in the first call, resulting in the operation `[1,2] + [1]`, giving `[1,2,1]`, and `[10]` in the second call, with `[10,20] + [10]` resulting in `[10,20,10]`.   The `map()` operation in the call would combine these arrays into `[[1,2,1],[10,20,10]]`.

---

In the function

```
def addvalue(f): f as $x | map(. + $x);
```

you call `map()` on what's assumed to be an array in the input stream.  For each element in the input array you add `$x` to that element. The value of `$x` is the arrays first element.

You call this function once, with the array `[[1,2],[10,20]]` as the input array and with `[1,2]` as the argument.  For each of the elements of the input array, i.e. for `[1,2]` and `[10,20]`, you add `[1,2]` (the value of `$x`, the array's first element).  Adding an array to another array has the effect of appending the elements of the arrays to each other, so you end up with `[1,2,1,2]` and `[10,20,1,2]` as two elements of the resulting array.

Enabling debugging in the second function in a similar way as in the first,

```
def addvalue(f): debug | f as $x | map(. + $x);
```

we get as output

```
["DEBUG:",[[1,2],[10,20]]]
```

This shows that the function is called a single time.  The `map()` operation would create an array where each element of the input array has `[1,2]` added to itself, giving `[[1,2,1,2],[10,20,1,2]]` as the result.

---

To make the first function act as the second, you would have to call it using

```
.[0] as $x | map(addvalue($x[]))
```

To make the second function act as the first, you would have to call it as

```
[ .[] as $x | [$x] | addvalue([$x[0]]) | add ]
```